# Passing the variable through delegate with ref parameter

Tags: c#, events, delegates, invoke

Have such delegates:

```
public delegate void GraphInit(ref DataMedia media);
public delegate void GraphStop(ref DataMedia media);
```

I want to use smth like that:

```
    void VideoRenderProcess(object sender, VideoRenderingArgs r_args)
    {
        DataMedia obj_mdata = sender as DataMedia;

        switch (obj_mdata.state)
        {
            case GraphState.Running:
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new GraphStop(ref obj_mdata));
                break;
            ......
        }
    }
```

Where `VideoRenderingArgs` is self-designed class:

```
public class VideoRenderingArgs
{
    public string uri { get; set; }
}
// it's just one string, of course I'm planning to add many other details
// which relate to video, but it's other story
```

`GraphStop()` method is:

```
    void GraphStop(ref DataMedia media)
    {
        if (media.mre_demux_conf != null) media.mre_demux_conf.WaitOne(2000);

        lock (this)
        {
            if (media.i_main_control != null)
            {   
                media.i_main_control.Stop();
                media.state = GraphState.Stopped;
            }
        }

        GraphClean();
    }
```

I'm getting error:

> 'obj_mdata' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'both with using
>   `ref` and not using.

How to do what I want in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the solution:

```
        public delegate void DGraphInit(ref DataMedia media);
        ...
        if (obj_mdata.state == GraphState.Running)
        {
            object[] data = { obj_mdata };
            DGraphInit delegate2call = new DGraphInit(GraphInit);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate2call, data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use new to create a delegate. Just assign to the delegate variable the method that you want.

What happens if you try this:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => GraphStop(ref obj_mdata))
```

Also, you will run into trouble if your delegate has the same name as a method in the same scope!

[EDIT] The above only works on .Net 4.5 or later, unfortunately.

Comment: with your sample I'm getting `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type`. I working on COM-objects and interfaces from DirectShow, so it will be rather difficult not to use delegate/interfaces for it.

Comment: You are using .Net 4 or earlier then, I guess - since .Net 4.5 should support lambdas with Dispatcher.Invoke(). Actually, what type is your Dispatcher? Knowing that would help! None of the overloads here take a single parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: don't exist any solution for the earliar .net version?

Comment: I think I was looking at the wrong type of Dispatcher... what is the full type of the Dispatcher you are using?

Comment: I found some discussion about this here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/677777bd-0e05-46f1-a2f2-acd4d4820b35 - other than that, I can't be much more help unfortunately.